# Is all traffic using the file protocol (file://) for smb/samba shares routed through Tor using tor browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, windows, protocol

I need to connect anonymously to a remote samba server. This is possible using an url like:

```
file:///ip.to.the.server/share
```

in the Tor browser bundle - I've checked. My question is, can I be sure that this traffic is routed through Tor much like it would with normal HTTP protocol traffic? My concern is that the traffic would somehow be routed via the OS and use my real IP. I am running windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing on my own and my conclusion is that the connection is in fact established **outside** the tor browser sandbox. The tor browser is merely functioning as some kind of "window" for the ordinary OS-specific SMB communication. That means that the tor users actual private IP is used in this case. Good to know.